# TYPO3 9 Extbase: edit m:n relation from both parent and child elements in backend form

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, extbase, typo3-9.x

In my extension I have two models: the **parent model** being **research groups** of a doctoral program, the **child model** being **application rounds** *(with opening and closing dates).* In an intermediate table I store the relationship between the two for research groups participating in application rounds. The application rounds can overlap with certain groups participating in two parallel rounds. That is the reason why I needed to make it an m:n relation. I made it all work using the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/4-FirstExtension/Index.html).

Whereas I can select multiple application rounds in the research groups form, I additionally want to make the backend form of the application rounds show a list of all groups to select from.

I found the [information on inline fields](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#attributes-on-anti-symmetric-intermediate-table) which shows a bidirectional use – but I am struggling translating this into my extension’s situation.

***Note:*** I do not want inline edits, really only selectCheckBox lists on both sides.

The `Groups` domain model contains the following property:

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Myvendor\Researchgroups\Domain\Model\ApplicationRounds>
 */
protected $applicationRounds = NULL;
```

persisted in the database by `application_rounds INT(10)`

The `Groups` TCA contains the following definition:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_researchgroups_domain_model_groups']['columns'] = [
    'application_rounds' => [
        'label' => '' . $locLang . 'groups.recruitingSelection',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_researchgroups_domain_model_applicationrounds',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_researchgroups_domain_model_applicationrounds.date_open DESC',
            'MM' => 'tx_researchgroups_groups_applicationrounds_mm',
            'eval' => 'int',
        ],
    ],
]
```

How do I add a corresponding select list to the `ApplicationRounds` model? Do I have to add a property there as well, persisted in the database – even thought that would be redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set [`mm-opposite-field`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#mm-opposite-field):

> If you want to make a MM relation editable from the foreign side (bidirectional) of the relation as well, you need to set MM_opposite_field on the foreign side to the field name on the local side.

*[edit by original questioner] see [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887177/4274248) for the full code based on this answer*

Comment: Thank you! According to this [tutorial on typo3tiger](https://www.typo3tiger.de/blog/post/typo3-bidirektionale-mm-relation-tca-extbase.html) which I found thanks to your hint, I have to add a field `researchgroups INT(11)` to the child model database table as well. Is that right? Or is it possible to avoid this? I was able to get the list displayed with the correct groups pre-selected but on hitting Save I got the error message that the field `researchgroups` does not exist.

Comment: of course you need a 'backlink' field. otherwise you couldn't edit from there.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Now it works – although from a database point of view this shouldn’t be necessary, I suppose.

Comment: in general you do not need this 'anchor' fields as the mm-records have all information. the anchor fields might have historical reason as TYPO3 formerly stored uid lists in this relation fields (and had no mm-records). later you still needed a placeholder to edit the relation in the backend. the fields are int as the number of relations is stored (so this information is not fully reliable). and of course you need the fields if you have multiple relations for different purpose to the same kind of records (have look at ext:news. multiple relations to files possible)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the full working code I added following the hints in [Bernd’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6796354/bernd-wilke-%cf%80%cf%86) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884148/4274248):

`ApplicationRounds` TCA (child model)

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_researchgroups_domain_model_applicationrounds']['columns'] = [
    'researchgroups' => [
        'label' => '' . $locLang . 'researchgroups_applicationrounds.recruitingGl',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_researchgroups_domain_model_groups',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_researchgroups_domain_model_groups.hidden = 0 ORDER BY tx_researchgroups_domain_model_groups.last_name ASC',
            'MM' => 'tx_researchgroups_groups_applicationrounds_mm',
            'MM_opposite_field' => 'last_name',
            'eval' => 'int',
        ],
    ],
]
```

(don’t forget to add `researchgroups` to `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_researchgroups_domain_model_applicationrounds']['types'][1]`)

And add a field to the database table of the child model:
`researchgroups INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`

I did not add `researchgroups` to the domain model though.